# GET and POST to ASP.NET MVC 3 from Windows Phone

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windows-phone-7

I have an app that I am migrating to use ASP.NET MVC 3. This app has a variety of GET and POST operations that are accessed via JQuery and exposed via MVC 3. The general idea is shown here:

**JQuery**

```
var vm = { param1:"someValue", param2:"someValue", param3: "someValue" };
$.ajax({
  url: http://localhost:49812/actions/postAction,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(vm),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: call_Succeeded,
    error: call_Failed
  });

function call_Succeeded(result) {
  // Do Stuff
}

function call_Failed(p1, p2, p3) {
  // Do Stuff
}
```

**Fiddler**

```
http://localhost:49812/actions/postAction 

{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2","param3":"value3"}
```

**ASP.NET MVC 3 Controller**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult PostAction(string param1, string param2, string param3)
{
  // Do stuff
  return Json(new { Message="Success!" });
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult GetAction(string param1, string param2, string param3)
{
  // Do stuff
  return Json(new { Message="Success!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I am trying to interact with these ASP.NET MVC 3 endpoints using C# on Windows Phone. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to GET and POST via the WebClient and WebRequest objects. The specific piece that is giving me problems is passing in the parameters. No matter what I do, I get a 404 error. Can someone show me how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: take a look at the WebClient.Uploadvalues method. It takes URL, methos (POST/GET) and a NameValueCollection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900ted1f.aspx

Comment: UploadValues doesn't exist in the Windows Phone SDK :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be sure, have you replaced *localhost* with the actual webserver name (deployed on IIS since Cassini doesn't accept external request) ?

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: http://localhost:49812/actions/postAction, 
    type: "POST", 
    data: JSON.stringify(vm), 
    contentType: "application/json", 
    success: call_Succeeded, 
    error: call_Failed 
  });
```

Comment: Can detail on are you testing on the phone/emulator ? and when do you get the 404?